# Saving Dictionary as Python Script

Tags: python, dictionary, copy, save

I'm somewhat new to Python.  I have a very long process that calculates a dictionary where keys are tuples on floats, and values are lists of floats.  I want to run the same script multiple times but only comput the dictionary once.  I would also like to be able to access the dictionary on other scrits.  My idea was to compute the dictionary and write it to another .py file that I could just import in any script I want.  I've found a lot of stuff on writing data to a txt file, and reading a txt file, but is there a quick way of writing directly to another .py file?  That is, I would like something like:

```
def Complicated_Process():

      Compute some dictionary D
      write D to file.py
```

```
import file.py

D = the dictionary in file.py
```

Comment: Save your data as [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) into a file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the pickle package, comes with python so no need to install any new packages.
This lets you save your dict to a file, and use in other scripts.

```
# Save a dictionary into a pickle file.
import pickle
    
favorite_color = {"lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red"}
    
pickle.dump(favorite_color, open("save.p", "wb"))

# Load the dictionary back from the pickle file.
    
favorite_color = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
# favorite_color is now {"lion": "yellow", "kitty": "red"}
```

https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that saving data as a `JSON` is the safe option, however `JSON` only supports strings as the keys and you have a tuple of floats. You can import variables between python modules, so in `compute.py` you have:

```py
def complicated_computation():
    ...
    return data
MY_DATA = complicated_computation()
```

then from your other modules have:

```py
from compute import MY_DATA
...
```

if you do this from several places you should only compute once, provided you are still running in the same python kernel.